# update angular form from javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm new to Angular. I've got an Angular js form that has rendered and works properly (updates, etc). I have a scenario where I want to populate form values based on user action after the form has rendered. So if the user takes a certain action, the values in a dropdown box, checkbox, input, etc, are preset in a certain way. I can get everything working except the last step.

From javascript, how do I update the data displayed on the form?

I've gone so far as to use

```
document.getElementById('123').value = 'my new default'
```

and although that works for plain text input fields, it doesn't change things like select dropdown boxes. They accept the new value, but still display a blank value. Is there any easy way to do this through the Angular framework?

Comment: you need some readings here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 0):

You can update the value on an html form using angularjs like so:

```js
angular.module('HelloWorldApp', [])
   .controller('HelloWorldController', function($scope) {
       $scope.greeting = "Hello World";
       $scope.UpdateForm = function(){
       $scope.greeting= "Updated!";
       }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div ng-app="HelloWorldApp">
    <div ng-controller="HelloWorldController">
       <input ng-model="greeting" />
       <button ng-click="UpdateForm()">Update Form</button>
    </div>
</div>
 </html>
```

To get started with angular, I really enjoyed watching this video

[Angular in 50 examples part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRrL5j3MIvo)